# what is the right way to call to constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, copy-constructor

```
    Communicator communicator = Communicator();

    Communicator communicator;
```

What is the difference between these 2 calls?

Comment: there's no difference, but second one is concise and should be preferred

Comment: Arguably one difference is one is longer to write. Maybe this won't feel like much in small examples, but when you start writing lots of code and calling many constructors, it'll make a difference. Also, personally, I find the second more readable, as the first looks slightly more like a _getter_

Comment: To be more clear you could write `Communicator communicator{};`

Comment: Semantically, the first constructs a temporary `Communicator` using the default constructor, and then constructs `communicator` by copying that temporary, after which the temporary ceases to exist.   Practically, compilers may (and in later standards will) elide the temporary, so there is no difference.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ A function with curly braces?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Bernd is correct (C++11 and later).   `Communicator communicator()` is a function declaration (the most vexing parse).    The uniform initialisation syntax `Communicator communicator{}` corrects that.    And a function definition always has a set of zero or more arguments in `()` before the first `{` is encountered.

Comment: @Peter Maybe, the emphasize was on _looks like_ ... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff - πάνταῥεῖ edited the comment.   My comment was in response to the pre-edit comment.    And, whether it "looks like" or not - it isn't.

Comment: @Scheff Happens when I miss to put my glasses on, sorry.

Comment: @Moia There is a difference. Try to do both with `std::atomic` in C++11/14.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "Glasses" was precisely which came in my mind as well. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in copy elision. Before C++17, in the line

```
Communicator communicator = Communicator();
```

a temporary `Communicator` object was created and then used to copy-construct `communicator`. A compiler could optimize this out but it had to check that that copy or move constructor can be invoked (public, not deleted, not `explicit`).

Since C++17, [copy elision rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) have changes: "unmaterialized value passing" was introduced. Now in that line no temporary object is created and no copy/move constructor is needed.

The following simple code will compile in C++17, but [will fail to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/7vss3T) in C++11/14:

```
class Communicator {
public:
    Communicator() = default;
    Communicator(const Communicator&) = delete;
};

Communicator c = Communicator();
```